# Suppressing remarks when not needed

Tags: environments, conditionals, comments

I have written some remarks in some of my works that are somewhat informal and repetitive in nature (mainly for my own clarification). I was wondering if there is a way of suppressing them when I don't want to typeset them in the PDF.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}

\section{Inner Loop (for $l$)}

We begin with inner loop - s.t. the given constraints, we find the optimal
level for individual labour supply in equilibirum,
\begin{equation*}
l=l^{\star }.
\end{equation*}

\begin{remark}
I want to keep this remark.
\end{remark}

\begin{remark}
When necessary, I would like to typeset this remark on or off.
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`comment` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/comment) provides this functionality via the environment `comment`. One could also specify a new comment environment that could be included/excluded. See the [`comment` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/comment/comment.pdf) for more information.

A more straight-forward way is to use conditionals in LaTeX:

1. Define a `\newif`;
2. Set the value to `true` to show the comments (say);
3. Set the value to `false` to hide the comments (say).

Here's a minimal example that defines `\ifkeepremark` as a `\newif` and sets it to `true` (`\keepremarktrue`) or `false` (`\keepremarkfalse`) depending on whether you need it or not:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newif\ifkeepremark
\begin{document}
\section{Inner Loop (for $l$)}

We begin with inner loop - s.t. the given constraints, we find the optimal
level for individual labour supply in equilibirum,
\begin{equation*}
  l=l^{\star}.
\end{equation*}

\keepremarktrue
\ifkeepremark
I want to keep this remark.
\fi

\keepremarkfalse
\ifkeepremark
When necessary, I would like to typeset this remark on or off.
\fi
\end{document}
```

It is possible to maintain the `remark` environment look using the [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ). It allows for environment definition in a control sequence style:

```
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\newif\ifkeepremark \keepremarktrue
\NewEnviron{remark}{\ifkeepremark\BODY\fi}
```

You could then still use

```
\begin{remark}
Here is a remark.
\end{remark}
```

together with the "switches" `\keepremarktrue` and `\keepremarkfalse` to selectively keep/discard `remark`s. The default value is `\keepremarkfalse`, which I've overridden with an issue of `\keepremarktrue`. That is, by default, *all* `remark`s will be visible.

You could also define your own `remark` environments based on other/alternative `\newif`s that you can turn on/off in the preamble (for a global modification).

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at `comment` package. Is it possible to have the standard look of Remark [or any `environment`] whilst using the requested feature?

Comment: @bakul: I've added the use of the [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ). That allows you to define a `remark` environment that you can use the conditionals with.