# Hiding an environment that contains minted code

Tags: verbatim, minted, code, ifthenelse

**Task:** I want to create a 'notes' command and an environment which can be hidden by a boolean flag.

**Problem:** These 'notes' can contain `minted` code blocks which mess up previous solutions found on the internet. Furthermore, we'd like to be able to enable / disable the flag locally.

**Circumstances:**

- we are creating a file containing multiple subfiles
- we'd like to be able to set the flag when building a subfile separately

**Research:**

- [Hide custom environment content based on boolean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15509/hide-custom-environment-content-based-on-boolean)

  - `ifthen` (doesn't exclude the code properly but would allow for local settings of the flag)

    ```
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    \newboolean{shownotes}
    %
    %\setboolean{shownotes}{true}
    \setboolean{shownotes}{false}
    %
    \newcommand{\notes}[1]{
      \ifthenelse{\boolean{shownotes}}{#1}{}
    }
    ```
  - `comment` (but `\excludecomment{notesenv}` doesn't do the job) and
  - `environ` (but `\NewEnviron{notesenv}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{shownotes}}{\BODY}{}}` also doesn't do the job)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/1d4p2a/how_to_hide_an_environment_ie_proof/
- http://www.ryanmartinphd.com/custom-environment-in-latex-that-can-be-hidden/
- [Suppressing remarks when not needed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45702/suppressing-remarks-when-not-needed)

**Current solution:** So far, I've come up with this bit which works well – except that I cannot overwrite the flag locally.

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{shownotes}}{%
    \newcommand{\notes}[1]{Notes: #1}%
    \newenvironment{notesenv}{Notes:}{}
}{%
    \newcommand{\notes}[1]{}
    \usepackage{environ}
    \NewEnviron{notesenv}{} % omitting the \BODY command creates a hidden environment
}
```

The flag cannot be overwritten locally as it needs to be set accordingly when making the definition. I guess I could copy the definition to every file, but is that really the only solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you try `\newif`?

Comment: I did not before, but now that I do I get the same behaviour as previously. It properly hides normal text (like the ifthen package), but as soon as you plug in some code environment it all breaks.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can use `\inputminted` with `NewEnviron`.

For example:

```
\RequirePackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{hidden}[0][]{\if@hidden\else\BODY\fi}

...

\begin{hidden}
    \inputminted{c}{solution.c}
\end{hidden}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would actually work. Could you provide a full minimal document and a screenshot of the result to show that this solves the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not work for your environment `notesenv`. But for the `\notes` macro, you could create a new conditional `\ifincludenotes` with `\newif`. Locally you can set it true or false.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\newif\ifincludenotes
\includenotestrue

\newcommand{\notes}[1]{\ifincludenotes#1\fi}

\begin{document}

\notes{Note1}

{\includenotesfalse%
\notes{Note2}%
}

\notes{Note3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as stated above this does not resolve the standing problem that I want to hide code, i.e. verbatim environments generated with `minted`.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a very old question, but as it has not been solved yet, maybe the solution I found for my problem could help those who will read at this question now as happened to me.

I had the same problem in hiding a section with minted content, based on a variable to set at the top of the document.
I was able to solve the problem with a mix of `\newif` and the `version` package.

Here is my code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

%-- Block for content  hiding ---------------------------
\newif\ifxml    % define the if command to use to show/hide the content
\usepackage{version}
\newenvironment{xmlsection}{}{} % create the environment that will contain the document part to show/hide

\xmltrue    % set \xmlfalse to hide the XML part

\ifxml \else \excludeversion{xmlsection} \fi % the ifelse clause to show/hide the section "xmlsection"
%-- Block end -------------------------------------------

\date{}
\title{My Title}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    A sentence with \ifxml something to be shown only with xmltrue and \fi some text.

    \begin{xmlsection} % the part of the document that will be shown/hidden
    \section{Section with XML code}
    Some text.\\

    \begin{minted}[tabsize=2, fontsize=\footnotesize, breaklines, breakanywhere=false, autogobble, samepage]{XML}
        <rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
        <channel>
            <!-- ... some XML tags -->
        </channel>
        </rss>
    \end{minted}

    \newpage
    \end{xmlsection}

    Other document sections\ldots
\end{document}
```

Hope this helps :)